# android:if app is open automattically gprs will enable

Tags: android

If app open , auttomatically gps enable if aldready is enable is not the problem  if does not enable want enable..

If app open , auttomatically gps enable if aldready is enable is not the problem  if does not enable want enable

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "automatically enable gprs",
If gprs radio is not on when we open our app, then we can ask the user to open it through request in an alert dialog and can navigate user to the setting app where it can enable it. this is the only possible and recommended way.